# What is the interpretation in statmech of $\left\langle\delta\left(\vec{v}-\frac{{\vec{p}}_i}{m}\right)\right\rangle$? Is it mean velocity $\vec{v}$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am studying statistical mechanics and I encountered the following equation (in canonical ensemble)

$$\left\langle\delta\left(\vec{v}-\frac{{\vec{p}}_i^2}{2m}\right)\right\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\int{\frac{d\Gamma}{N!h^{3N}}e^{-\beta H(\Gamma)}\cdot\delta\left(\vec{v}-\frac{{\vec{p}}_i^2}{2m}\right)}$$

My question is about the interpretation of the equation: $\left\langle\delta\left(\vec{v}-\frac{{\vec{p}}_i}{m}\right)\right\rangle$. What exactly would this equation be in words? My guess would be “the expectation of the proportion of particles with momenta ${\vec{p}}_i$ such that the velocities of the particles are  $\vec{v}$.”

Or in other words the proportion of particles having velocity $\vec{v}$. Or is it the mean velocity $\vec{v}$?

What is the correct interpretation of $\left\langle\delta\left(\vec{v}-\frac{{\vec{p}}_i}{m}\right)\right\rangle$?

In statistical mechanics, what is the interpretation of $\left\langle\delta\left(\vec{v}-\frac{{\vec{p}}_i}{m}\right)\right\rangle$? Is it the mean velocity $\vec{v}$?

Answer (score 2):

When a function of $x'$ times a Dirac delta $\delta(x-x')$ is integrated over $x'$, the resulting value of the integral is a function of $x$, not a number, Therefore your integral cannot be the mean value of the velocity.

Its meaning can be clarified by looking at $\delta \left(\vec v - \frac{\vec p_i}{m} \right)$ as a generalized function of $\vec v$, at fixed $\frac{\vec p_i}{m} $, revealing if the value of its argument $\vec v$ is equal to the parameter $\frac{\vec p_i}{m}$. In other words, once one fixes the value of $\frac{\vec p_i}{m}$, the integral of the delta over a small volume in the velocity space  $\vec v$ will give $1$ if the volume contains the value  $\frac{\vec p_i}{m}$, and $0$ otherwise.

If $\frac{\vec p_i}{m}$ is not a fixed value but a stochastic variable with a probability density $\rho\left(\frac{\vec p_i}{m}\right)$ the integral
$$
\int \rho\left(\frac{\vec p_i}{m}\right) \delta \left(\vec v - \frac{\vec p_i}{m} \right)=\rho(\vec v)
$$
is nothing but the probability density of the event $\vec v = \frac{\vec p_i}{m}$.